Binary response vs probability response
Consider these two scenarios:

respondents are asked to choose between two options offered to them (the resulting data is binary 0 & 1)
respondents are asked to give their probability of choice between the two options (data is continuous between 0 & 1)

For case 1: the probability of choice_1, is estimated by taking the percentage of number of yeses for option_1.
For case 2: let's take the average of probabilities given to option_1.
How can these two scenarios be compared based on statistical criteria (e.g. efficiency and robustness)? My prior is that case one is generally less efficient but more robust.

How are you operationally defining "efficiency" and "robustness" for these comparisons?

@ Galen I take efficiency as lower variance and robustness as less sensitive to errors (e.g. more restricted influence function). One can think of scenario_1 as a restricted form of scenario_2 by setting y=1 if p(y)>0.5 and zero otherwise therefore scenario_2 contains more information hence more efficient.

Let $\theta \in (0,1)$ be the parameter of interest that represents the probability of "choice 1."  In the Bernoulli case, respondent $i$ provides a choice $X_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ where $X_i = 1$ if they choose option 1, and $0$ otherwise.
We know that the proportion of $1$s (i.e., $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$) is an unbiased efficient estimator with variance $\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}$.
Now in the second case, it is unclear what model you are specifying for the response.  One possibility is to suppose that it is in fact discrete, say a percentage between $0$ and $100\%$, so a binomial model with $m = 100$ and $p = \theta$ could be used, and let $$100 Y_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(m = 100, p = \theta)$$ represent the probability they would choose option 1.  The corresponding unbiased estimator is $\bar Y$, which is also efficient, but has variance $\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{100n}$.
But this model is not necessarily a meaningful way to represent what is happening in the second case, because it assumes that a respondent is in some sense internally choosing a probability that is the average of $100$ independent Bernoulli trials (hence underdispersed).  This defect becomes especially apparent as one lets $m \to \infty$.
A more sophisticated model would be to suppose that each respondent's probability of choosing option 1 is a beta random variable $B_i$ with general parameters $a, b$ which are chosen in a way such that $\operatorname{E}[B_i] = \frac{a}{a+b} = \theta$.  Then again, the sample mean $\bar B$ by linearity of expectation yields an unbiased estimator for $\theta$.  Its variance is
$$\operatorname{Var}[\bar B] = \frac{ab}{n (a+b)^2(a+b+1)} = \frac{\theta^2 (1-\theta)}{n(a+\theta)}.$$
So the relative efficiency is
$$\frac{\operatorname{Var}[\bar B]}{\operatorname{Var}[\bar X]} = \frac{\theta}{a + \theta} < 1$$ since $a > 0$, illustrating that $\bar X$ is less efficient for any choice of beta parameters, but not in a way that depends on the granularity of the response probability.
As for robustness, that depends on how you model case 2--the beta distribution I used is not the only possible choice.  Moreover, you need to specify in what sense an estimator should be regarded as "robust."

Thanks for the answer. My issue was also the model for the second scenario. modelling using beta distn seems reasonable.
